# How to send notification from the background via an HTTP api (without push notifications) in Flutter?

Tags: http, notifications, flutter

So, I was working on a Android application in java that used GcmTaskService to schedule a service and make HTTP requests in the background with HttpsURLConnection (about every 10 minutes) and if the content changed, it would send a notification to the user. This might not have been the best way to do this, but it worked and that was enough for me.

Now I want to rewrite the app in Flutter, with similar logic. I know iOS is very strict when it comes to background work so I would be fine with the request being made at non-exact times (1-2 times a day is OK).

In Flutter I am using `http.get();` (get data) and `http.post();` (login and get Bearer code) to get the necessary data.

Unfortunately I only found tutorials on this topic with FCM and push notifications.
Implementing push notifications is not an option for now, since I was given no access to the server backend.

Is there another way to do this with simple HTTP requests to the API?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/F0kFb2B3) is the old implementation in Java.

Comment: This is not supported by Flutter directly, yet. You can find the whole discussion here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24278 nowaydays, user notifications should be handled differently (firebase, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think [`background_fetch`](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) is what you want. But you need to be careful, if you plan to support iOS - see [here](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/issues/28) and [here](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch/issues/159).