# Changing Flutter application state based on another client's response

Tags: c#, firebase, flutter

I apologize in advance - this is a super, super high level question, and I don't know how to ask it.

I have an application that creates meetings between people by returning a list of results in between them.

I am trying to replicate the functionality using Flutter, but the difference is that with Flutter I need a way to update the state of the application when User B responds to User A.

Flow:

- User A makes a meeting invite.
- User B should receive meeting invite.
- User B accepts meeting invite.
- Server updates User A with some information.

Right now, I am making an async call to my application server - it mocks the location for User B and sends the list of venues back.

However, in reality, I will not have the data for User B until User B gets the request and issues a response.

I've considered using Firebase Cloud Messaging, but there isn't as much support for a C# application hosted in Azure acting as an application server for Firebase Cloud Messaging / Firebase. I can certainly look into it more, but I'm just asking to see if there are alternatives.

My understanding is:

- User A makes request.
- Application server processes it - stores in SQL that a request was made.
- Notes the User A's name.
- Notes User B's name.
- Makes a push notification to User B.
- User B accepts or declines.
- User B's device makes a request to the server.
- Server looks up the response from User B, finds User A.
- Makes a push notification to device of User A.

My question is, is there a way to do this without relying on push notifications?

More simply, how do I update the mobile app outside of the initial request/response without using a push notification, if that's at all possible?

It seems to me that in my initial request, I have to respond with the data the client needs (which wouldn't be available until the respondee answers), so I'd need a background task or something.

I'm very new to client-side development, so I don't know how else I can handle this.

edit:
For clarity, I can make a post to the server from the client - it sent the data from User A, and it persists it to a SQL database.

Currently, the response is immediately the data that would've come from Device B that I "mocked". Meaning I wrote dummy data to return to Device A. In reality, this wouldn't happen, so I need to make a "request" to update Device B and Device A somehow.

Now, I am unsure of how to "reach" the other device through anything other than Firebase for push notifications.

I've also looked at:
[How to send notification from the background via an HTTP api (without push notifications) in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141811/how-to-send-notification-from-the-background-via-an-http-api-without-push-notif)

While a solution, I specifically need it to be faster than 15 minutes - sometimes almost real-time. Is this possible?